# External Display Keeps Switching Refresh Rates After Waking From Sleep

Tags: macos, display, resolution, bug

I recently set up my new Mac Studio with my Samsung CRG9 external monitor, that supports up to a 5120 X 1440 resolution at 120Hz. I set my Mac Studio to run at that resolution and refresh rate, but for some reason whenever I wake my Mac from sleep, the refresh rate will switch to the "Variable (48Hz-120Hz)" setting. I don't want the variable refresh rate on this display, I would like it to just stick to the full 120Hz refresh rate at that resolution at all times because it makes moving things around the display a bit jittery when using the variable one. Not sure why it's switching back to variable after waking it from sleep but is there a way to prevent this?

Like I said, using a new Mac Studio running macOS 12.3.1, and a Samsung CRG9 external display.

Comment: This appears to happen regardless of the display, but many users may not notice if their display works better with variable refresh. My BenQ 32" 4K flickers like crazy in variable refresh, so this macOS bug (of resetting the preference on every wake-from-sleep / restart) is extremely annoying.

Answer (score 6):

Found a fix right after posting this: Had to turn off FreeSync on my external display in its settings menu. Hopefully this helps someone else having this same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not all displays support turning off variable refresh rates, so this isn't really a general solution for the macOS issue of resetting the preference every time it wakes from sleep.

Comment: Omg thank you, this was driving me insane

Comment: Also GSync, Mac doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem.  Apple "Help" guided me through turning my computer on in safe mode (I did not need this guidance by the way) and we were unable to change the behavior.  They reverted to telling me to look it up in the monitor's manual as I'm using an Acer KG27U1.  This is not acceptable support.
This seems like a fundamental development error on Apple's part.  Users should be able to save settings and turn them off or on and not have them automatically and inevitably change. I look forward to Apple going bankrupt or them listening to their users and actually making something better instead of worse for once.  Neither scenario seems likely.

P.S.- There is no way to turn off adaptive sync in my monitor settings.  There is no option for anything relating to refresh rate in my monitor settings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using [EasyRes](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/easyres/id688211836?mt=12) (free at App Store) may be a workaround before Apple finally realize the problem is on their side.

Turning off FreeSync/AdaptiveSync on display's OSD is quite annoying as I also use my display for gaming on Windows, in which case VRR may be better. Also as others commented, not all displays can disable VRR. The problem is definitely Apple's fault.

I use external GPU and can confirm this problem still exists in Monterey 12.6.1 and Ventura 13.0, or at least with my eGPU setup.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved with Monterey 12.4
Now when i restart the mac, it save 165hz fix mode. (mac mini m1 to benq ex2710q). Now you can turn off FreeSync

Comment: Restarting doesn't work here. 9/10 times after restarting or waking from sleep, the Display preference has switched back to variable refresh rate and it's flickering like crazy again.